# Objective-C: Two 'identical' strings do not match?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a two strings.

Once is a response from a TCP server using NSStream events, using:

```
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

And one is a string produced from on the fly, that *should* match the returned string from the NSStream.

I have NSLog both of these out, and they are identical.
I have tried to NSLog the Lengths of the strings, and one is two characters longer - Even though they are both identical in 'text' form.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

I need to know if they match, as if they do, another event will be triggered to enhance and add additional functionality to my app.

Comment: Please show us how you compare the strings

Comment: Sounds like you may have a carriage return, newline, or a tab in there if it's showing two extra characters that do not display using `NSLog`.

Comment: One of them may be 2 characters longer because of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Try trimming any whitespace and newline characters off the ends, and see if that makes the lengths the same.

Comment: I have tried: if(output==checkOutput) and also if([output isEqualTo:checkOutput]) and also caseInsensitiveSearch with NSOrderedSame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys.

Fixed with @rdelmar suggestions - I didn't know this was possible in Objective-C:

```
NSString *trimOutput = [output stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use == to compare strings. If their contents are character-by-character identical, you can use isEqualToString to compare 2 strings. If your strings have different lengths, though, then they are not character-by-character identical.

Write a for loop that uses the method characterAtIndex to log the characters from each string 1 at a time and compare them. You might need to log the characters' integer values so you can see info about the non-printable ones.

Comment: `characterAtIndex` has the interesting property that it does not necessarily return an entire character, it returns a unichar which is 16-bits. But many characters are more than 16-bits such as emoji, non-composed characters, flag symbols, etc.

Comment: That is only an issue if you use unicode characters that can't be expressed in 16 bits.

Comment: Yep, and we are seeing a lot of emoji which are 17-bit (plane 1) characters.